# How to remove last node of a linked list (Python)

Tags: python, listview, linked-list, python-3.6, tail-recursion

The goal is to remove the last node of a linked list. (Python)  The code that I have written only added to the list instead of taking the tail away. I'm not sure if the error is coming from this part here self.head.next.prev = None. I tried refining that part but another error would occurred. What I have posted is only small section of the code.

```
def remove_tail(self):
        if self.tail == self.head:
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None
        elif self.head is not None:
            self.head.next.prev = None
            self.tail = self.head.next
```

```
print("\n=========== PROBLEM 2 TESTS ===========")
ll.remove_tail()
print(ll) # linkedlist[5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
ll.remove_tail()
print(ll) # linkedlist[5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

I reverse the names of head and tail to see of that was causing the issues.

```
elif self.head is not None:
            self.head.next.prev = None
            self.tail = self.head.next
```

Here is the updated code. Errors still occur when I run it.

```
def remove_tail(self):
    if self.tail == self.head:
     self.head = None
     self.tail = None
    if self.tail is not None:
     self.tail = self.tail.prev
     self.tail.next = None
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `self.head.next.prev = None` This code assumes that there are only two nodes.  Why would you assume that?

Comment: Oh! How can you make it assume that it has more than two nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Think about the structure of the list (assuming you have more than one element; your code already handles that special case):

```
head                 tail
+---+->+---+->+---+->+---+->None
| 1 |  | 2 |  | 3 |  | 4 |
+---+<-+---+<-+---+<-+---+
```

If you remove the last element, you're going to have:

```
head          tail 
+---+->+---+->+---+->None  
| 1 |  | 2 |  | 3 |
+---+<-+---+<-+---+
```

What needs to change in order for that to happen?

- `tail` needs to be set to the second-to-last node (3, aka `tail.prev`)
- the new `tail`'s `next` pointer needs to be set to `None` (since the old `tail`, 4, is no longer part of the list)

So instead of:

```
self.head.next.prev = None
self.tail = self.head.next
```

you want:

```
self.tail = self.tail.prev
self.tail.next = None
```

Comment: The example you have make sense.  This error came up when I run the code. Attribute error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: You probably want to check that `self.tail != self.head`. The only way I can see that error occuring in the example is if `self.tail.prev` is `None`, and the only node where `prev` should be `None` is `self.head`. If `self.tail == self.head` then you probably want to do alternate processing, such as just removing the head like you already had in your code. You may also want to do an additional check to see if there is a head at all, and if there isn't just do nothing.

Comment: I guess you mean I need to remove  elif self.tail is not None:.